# Load csv file to Pandas DataFrame and add a new column with keyword taken from "keyword" rows

Tags: python, pandas, csv, slice

I have a .csv file with following format:

```
Cash
Serial,Date,Balance
1,2021-03-05,34
2,2021-05-04,54
Credit
Serial,Date,Balance
18,2021-03-05,898
21,2021-04-01,654
Savings
Serial,Date,Balance
3,2021-03-18,19384
34,2021-12-04,472
```

I want to load this into a pandas DataFrame with following structure

```
Serial,Asset,Date,Balance
1,Cash,2021-03-05,34
2,Cash,2021-05-04,54
18,Credit,2021-03-05,898
21,Credit,2021-04-01,654
3,Savings,2021-03-18,19384
34,Savings,2021-12-04,472
```

I could already load the file into a DataFrame using following code:

```py
import numpy as np

FILE = r"/myfile.csv"

with open(FILE, 'r') as temp_f:
    col_count = [ len(l.split(",")) for l in temp_f.readlines() ]

column_names = [i for i in range(0, max(col_count))]
df = pd.read_csv(FILE, header=None, delimiter=",", names=column_names)
df['Asset'] = np.nan
print(df)
```

but am stuck now how to delete the rows with "Serial,Date,Balance" and fill the rows in the asset column with the corresponding entry ("Cash", "Credit" etc.).
Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Note that your have a type Balance/Balace, I'm assuming this is a mistake?

Comment: Is your actual dataset contains 2 data rows for each asset?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo.
No, the amount of each asset is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CSV should have a single header, but this will read it as is:

```py
import pandas as pd
import csv

df = pd.DataFrame(columns='Serial Asset Date Balance'.split())

with open('myfile.csv', 'r', newline='') as temp_f:
    reader = csv.reader(temp_f)
    for line in reader:
        if len(line) == 1:   # Only one thing in the line?
            asset = line[0]  # remember it as the asset type
            next(reader)     # and skip the header line below it
        else: # add to the end of the dataframe
            df.loc[len(df.index)] = line[0], asset, line[1], line[2]

print(df)
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Output:

```
  Serial    Asset        Date Balance
0      1     Cash  2021-03-05      34
1      2     Cash  2021-05-04      54
2     18   Credit  2021-03-05     898
3     21   Credit  2021-04-01     654
4      3  Savings  2021-03-18   19384
5     34  Savings  2021-12-04     472
```

output.csv:

```
Serial,Asset,Date,Balance
1,Cash,2021-03-05,34
2,Cash,2021-05-04,54
18,Credit,2021-03-05,898
21,Credit,2021-04-01,654
3,Savings,2021-03-18,19384
34,Savings,2021-12-04,472
```

Comment: Yes indeed, unfortunately this is the format I receive from another program and try to process and get into the form of a .csv file.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a .csv file with following format

That is emphatically not a
[CSV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) file.
It is three such files:

- cash.csv
- credit.csv
- savings.csv

Store them that way in the filesystem.

Read in three separate dataframes.
Then do reporting on them in the usual way to
produce a single combined dataframe.
Hint: supplementing each small dataframe with
a constant text column of "cash",
or "credit" or "savings", will ease your task.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
import io

# Separate sections
data = {}
with open('data.csv') as fp:
    for row in fp:
        if ',' not in row:
            k = row.strip()
            data[k] = []
        else:
            data[k].append(row.strip())

# Build individual dataframes
dfs = []            
for asset, values in data.items():
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('\n'.join(values)))
    df.insert(1, 'Asset', asset)
    dfs.append(df)

# Merge them
df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   Serial    Asset        Date  Balance
0       1     Cash  2021-03-05       34
1       2     Cash  2021-05-04       54
2      18   Credit  2021-03-05      898
3      21   Credit  2021-04-01      654
4       3  Savings  2021-03-18    19384
5      34  Savings  2021-12-04      472
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regex with [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) to iterate over the chunks, with [`io.StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO)+[`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) to load each chunk and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to combine them into a single DataFrame:

```
import re, io
import pandas as pd

with open('myfile.csv') as f:
    out = pd.concat(
        {m.group(1): pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(m.group(2)))
        for m in re.finditer('(\w+)\n(.*?)\n(?=\w+\n|$)',
                                f.read(), flags=re.DOTALL)
        }, names=['Asset']).reset_index('Asset')
```

Output:

```
     Asset  Serial        Date  Balance
0     Cash       1  2021-03-05       34
1     Cash       2  2021-05-04       54
0   Credit      18  2021-03-05      898
1   Credit      21  2021-04-01      654
0  Savings       3  2021-03-18    19384
1  Savings      34  2021-12-04      472
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mL4e1m/1)